# Error when creating CSV-File with JSP (Tomcat 7/Java)

Tags: java, jsp, csv, tomcat7

I have an JSP-File, which creates a CSV-File.

To tell the server that the file is an CSV-File I added the following code to the JSP:

```
response.setContentType ("application/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv");
```

In the file I simply write the content of the file with an "Writer" object (the out-Variable).
Therefore I use the following code to gernerate the file:

```
out.write("test1;test2;etc");
```

There are about 16 columns for this csv-file with about 3000 rows.

The Problem I have is that the "Download file"-Dialog does not appear with bigger files. When I only have 128 rows it works and the Browser does show the "Download File"-windows. When I have 129 rows the browser simply opens the file with plain text (with the IE ignoring the line breaks). This happens in every browser I tested (IE 11 and Firefox). I actually have no idea why this happens, though my guess is that it has something to do with the Writer-Object. I already tried to "flush()" the Writer, but this doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
I did strip down the code to the following. When j is limited to 50 it does work. With is being set to 100, it doesn't. The .jsp is open with href.location or window.open() (it does not seem to make a difference)

```
<%
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {

        out.write(";");

        for (k = 0; k < 16; k++)
        {
            out.write(j + "TEST");

            if (k != 15)
            {
                out.write(";");
            }
        }

        out.write("\r\n");
    }


    response.setContentType ("application/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv"); 
%>
```

Comment: Any errors ? have you checked the stacktraces ?

Comment: Tomcat does not return any errors. To be honest, I'm not even sure if that is a problem of Tomcat/Java or the browser.

Comment: How try with `response.setContentLength(<file-size>)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Is there something like a maximum size for files or something like hat? I did try to set the the Content Length to a very huge size, which is much bigger than the actualy content being created.

Comment: check my answer i hope this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Change below configurations in your `tomcat` **webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml**.
we can change this setting , just put 0 on each size limit.
the finally configure :

```
  <multipart-config>
       <!-- 50MB max -->
       <max-file-size>524288000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>524288000</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
     </multipart-config>
```

Also check for ,

**maxPostSize**

The maximum size in bytes of the `POST` which will be handled by the container `FORM URL` parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to `2097152 (2 megabytes)`.

**Another Limit is:**

`maxHttpHeaderSize` The maximum size of the request and response HTTP header, specified in bytes. If not specified, this attribute is set to `4096 (4 KB)`.

You find them in

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml
```

Comment: I tried editing the connector in the server.xml: <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
              redirectPort="8443" 
      URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
      maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
      maxPostSize="0"
      /> and added your code to the web.xml. Still the csv-file opens as plain text in the browser as soon as the a high amount of lines is reached.

Comment: Sadly it does not. What also confuses me, is that there does not seem to be a line missing in the plain text. The only "error" is that the "Save File"-dialog does not appear anymore, which is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Jsp are great to produce HTML output.

As you want to produce csv, you'd better use a servlet. I did it and it works well with 50000 rows. Here is my demo code :

```
public class CsvServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv");
        response.setContentType ("application/csv");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        for (int i=0; i<50000; i++) {
            pw.print(i);
            for (char c: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray()) {
                pw.print(',');
                pw.print(c);
            }
            pw.println();
        }
    }

}
```